# How to set NO-REPLY email

Tags: plesk, parallels

Just wondering how I would go about setting up an "no-reply" email address, and by that I mean one that will discard all incoming mail. Not bouncing it, just discarding/deleting it.

Comment: You could probably set up a regular task in cpanel to trash all the emails sent to that address.

Comment: I forgot to mention that im working with plesk panel for windows dedicated servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually nothing need to do in Plesk, just set(send) emails with "From:" field of non-existent email address of your domain, like: no-reply@domain.tld or nobody@domain.tld or something other.

When somebody will sent mail to no-reply@domain.tld it will be rejected automatically, because of default Plesk settings:

[image: no-reply address with plesk]

[image]

Comment: how to send from non-existing email? it asking for SMTP host